# Add a canvas form element

Tags: 7, forms

I am developing a module and I have this HTML markup.

```html
<canvas id="cnv" name="cnv" width="500" height="100"></canvas>
```

I want to add it in a form. Looking at the [Form API reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#text_format) documentation page, I don't see any canvas form element.

What should I instead use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form api does not support every tag in HTML. For special cases use a form key of `#markup` to embed raw HTML. Scan the form APIs for that keyword for examples.

Answer (score 1):

[This document page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21HtmlTag.php/class/HtmlTag/8.2.x) might help you.

Here is a sample code that I wrote to create a canvas in my form in Drupal 8.

```
$form['canvas']=array(
      '#type' => 'html_tag',
      '#tag' => 'canvas',
      '#attributes' => array(
                    'style'=>'border: 1px solid #000000;
                              width: 200;
                              height: 100;'
                            ),
      );
```